# Python Open File Button

Tags: python, user-interface

I am having trouble, trying to get my open button to open a text file. I want it to open the text file into the not pad, when I click the open button. If some one could help me or tell me what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

```
def _open(self):
        open("../Address.txt","r").close()
        with open("../Address.txt", "a") as file:
            self._outputArea.insert("1.0", file.read)
            file.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why open and close the file first? Just use the `with` line.
- Don't use `file` as a variable name, it's also a type.
- You're not *calling* `read`.
- `'a'` is a flag for appending a file, use `'r'` (for read) instead.

Try something like:

```
def _open(self):
    with open("../Address.txt", "r") as the_file:
        self._outputArea.insert("1.0", the_file.read())
```

Comment: It gives me this error when I click the open button                                        File "E:\Mike's CPT-135 python class\Project2\src\GroupProject.py", line 226, in _open
    file.read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: Does the file exist yet?

Comment: it's not opening it to the text field aka not pad

Comment: Strange, I can't see why you'd get that error with the above code.

Comment: it's creating a text file, but I want it to open up in a note pad I have with in my program

Comment: I'm sorry I figure out the problem. I had two of the same files and one was blank and the other wasn't. It works great now thank you so much!!!